# Is there a way to automate restarting the python process after every change I make to Django models?

Tags: python, django, passenger, wsgi

I am using Django with Passenger on Dreamhost.

Every time I make a change to models, settings or views I need to pkill python from a terminal session.  Does anyone know of a way to automate this?  Is this something that Passenger can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to test locally using Django's builtin server.

It does precisely *auto-reload*, so that any change to your code will be available.

I'm not familiar with Dreamhost, but if modwsgi is on embedded mode this is not possible.
In Daemon mode, you could write some code to detect file changes and restart the processes.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks!  I skipped the builtin server exercise when I ran through the Django tutorials.  I guess I should have checked it out.  :)